Refresh rate not available on clean Linux Mint installation
My laptop has Linux Mint 21.3 installed, with a supported monitor, HDMI cable, and graphics card. It is limited to 3840x2160 30 Hz. I am using Intel(R) XE Graphics.
An existing Windows installation on this computer runs at 3840x2160 at 60.00 Hz.
I would like to run my Linux Mint at 3840x2160 at 60.00 Hz.
I've already tried forcing these display settings using cvt and xrandr, to no avail.
Output of xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1600     60.00 +
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 940mm x 530mm
   3840x2160     30.00*+  24.00    29.97    23.98  
   4096x2160     30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    30.00    59.94    29.97    24.00    23.98  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Thanks for the help.

Use the Display app.
Open the system menu, by clicking or hitting Super. Type 'display' (without the quotes). Complete the dialogue and click Apply.
(Screenshot from Mint 22 with Cinnamon)


Thanks for the reply. The option for the 60 Hz refresh rate does not display. The only other options are modes lower than 30 Hz.
Any other solutions?

No other solutions, but a couple of suggestions. Try posting your question on the Mint questions site: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewforum.php?f=47&sid=2a7dfba11a5f7b2ba32ae05a90d7815f . Remember to include your Edition (Cinnamon, Mate, etc.). Otherwise, you may consider upgrading to Mint 22.

Could it be an issue with your display driver?
From the system menu, start typing 'driver'. Select Driver Manager and let it examine your system. If it says, "No drivers needed", then that is not the problem. There is a guide to Driver Manager here: https://thelinuxcode.com/download-drivers-linux-mint/
